# Are Statements with Existential Quantifiers General or Particular?

Tags: philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

Consider the following argument:

> The number 2 is a prime number and is divisible by 2. Thus, some prime number is divisible by 2.

The first statement in this argument concerns a particular, i.e. the number 2. However, the second statement I'm not so sure about. It concerns an existential, an arbitrary element in the class of prime numbers. Is this second statement a general claim or a particular? In general, are claims defined by an existential quantifier in a class of objects considered to be general or particular?

Comment: I made an edit to format the argument so it stood out better. You are welcome to roll this back or continue editing. You may see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. Welcome to this SE!

Answer (score 3):

We have the tarditional view about [Categorical propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition#Quantity_and_quality), originated with [Aristotle's logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#AllSomNon).

A categorical proposition "is a proposition that asserts or denies that all or some of the members of one *category* (the *subject* term) are included in another (the *predicate* term).

According to this view, a *particular* proposition has the logical form : "Some S is P", which is translated in modern simbolic form with : **∃x(Sx ∧ Px)**.

But in modern predicate logic, the rule of inference that you have used is usuallly called [*Existential introduction* or *Existential generalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization).

We can call **∃xPx** a sort of *generalization* because the statement does not assert something about a particular, like e.g. Socrates in "Socrates is a philosopher", but asserts that a class is not empty (or a property is instantiated).

Comment: I can see this as a generalization and modified my answer based on yours.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the argument:

> The number 2 is a prime number and is divisible by 2. Thus, some prime number is divisible by 2.

Let "P" be the property that a natural number is prime and divisible by 2. Let "a = 2".

Then from the premise "Pa" we can validly prove that "∃xPx" using first-order logic.

The "x" in that conclusion is just a variable. It is not an "arbitrary element in the class of prime numbers", but it is one of the elements in the domain that has the property. We know there is one with that property because of the assumption "Pa". The "x" refers to any natural number in the domain that has the property "P" without assigning it a particular name, such as, "2" or "a".

Let's consider how some texts describe the existential quantifier.

Here is what Frederic Fitch says from *Symbolic Logic* written in 1952: (page 145)

> An attribute is said to be **non-empty** or **existent** if something has the attribute. Thus non-emptiness is an attribute of attributes. It applies to just those attributes which themselves apply to something. An attribute is empty if its complement is universal. It is non-empty if its complement is not universal.

One can think of "∃xPx" as the claim that the attribute "P" is non-empty.

Here is what the authors of *forall x* written in 2018 say about the existential quantifier: (page 160)

> In FOL, the domain must always include at least one thing.
>   Moreover, in English we can infer ‘something is angry’ from ‘Gregor is angry’. In FOL, then, we will want to be able to infer ‘∃xAx’
>   from ‘Ag’. So we will insist that each name must pick out exactly
>   one thing in the domain. If we want to name people in places
>   beside Chicago, then we need to include those people in the domain.

Using this example the existential quantifier claims that the property of being angry is non-empty. There is someone in the domain who is angry. However, the existential quantifier no longer only picks out Gregor. Someone besides Gregor may also be angry. It generalizes to pick out any of those people in the domain who are angry and there is at least one of them. (This last paragraph edited after reading [Mauro ALLEGRANZA's answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/56213/29944).)

---

References

Fitch, F. B. (1952). Symbolic logic.

Mauro ALLEGRANZA's answer, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/56213/29944

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: I'm not sure about that last quote: it seems to me that it says that names refer to specific things, not that existential quantifiers do. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EliranH I made an edit in the last paragraph hopefully addressing your concern.